# How many roots does the polynomial $acx^4 + b(a + c)x^3 + (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)x^2 + b(a + c)x + ac$ have

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, elementary-functions

Let a, b and c be real numbers. Then the fourth degree
polynomial in $x$, $acx^4 + b(a + c)x^3 + (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)x^2 + b(a + c)x + ac$

(a) Has four complex (non-real) roots
(b) Has either four real roots or four complex roots
(c) Has two real roots and two complex roots
(d) Has four real roots

I have no clue as to how to approach it, a hint would suffice

Answer (score 3):

HINT: write your equation in the form
$$(x(ax+b)+c)(a+x(b+cx))=0$$ and solve it

Answer (score 1):

HINT: use [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) and check conditions to get a certain number of roots of a certain type...